# Can i do simple maths in Active Record Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

i want to change the quantity of the item when the user saves a invoice
i use something like that `Item.find_by(itemName: 'kimas').update(:quantity => +7)` and for some reason it replace the old value, for example if  the value is 10 and run this `Item.find_by(itemName: 'kimas').update(:quantity => +7)` the value change to 7

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
        before_save :check_me
        before_update :check_me

    def check_me
        items = itemname.length
        i = 0
        while i < items
        item_new = Item.find_by(itemName: itemname[i])
        sumup = ( quantity[i] * price[i] + (quantity[i] * price[i] * tax[i]/100) )
        Item.find_by(itemName: 'kimas').update(:quantity => +=7)
        i += 1
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only set a **new** value using Active Record's `update`.

In your case `update(:quantity => +=7)` will actually raise `syntax error, unexpected operator-assignment)`.

The other form that you've used in this question `update(:quantity => +7)` is actually equivalent to `update(:quantity => 7)`, and is same as `update(quantity: 7)`. `+7` is just another way of saying `7`. As you've noticed this operation indeed only sets the new value to 7.

To solve your problem you could split your 1-liner into 2 lines:

1. store the item you've found in a variable
2. use variable's previous value to do your calculation

E.g. replace `Item.find_by(itemName: 'kimas').update(:quantity => +=7)` with:

```
item = Item.find_by(itemName: 'kimas')
item.update(quantity: item.quantity + 7)
```

Another option will be creating raw SQL code, but probably will be overkill for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Calling update like that is going to set that value to whatever you pass it and attempt to match the data type found on the quantity column (which I assume is integer), which is why you're getting 7 and not 17.

You can try something like this instead:

```
found_item = Item.find_by(itemName: 'kimas')
found_item.update(quantity: found_item.quantity + 7)
```